# Interesting Geometry Problem UKMT 2015/2016

Tags: geometry, contest-math

I have been doing some ukmt problems for fun but this one has seemed to stumbled me (Question 8 from the 2015/2016 seniour maths challenge group round http://www.furthermaths.org.uk/docs/1Group%20for%20teams.pdf). I get that if I name the sides of each square $a,b,c,d,e$  starting from the biggest square clockwise I get that $a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2+e^2=2016$. We want to find the area of the pond, which is its side squared call it $\mu$. By Pythagorous $\mu^2=b^2+c^2$ and by similar triangles $\mu=d$. Then, $a^2+\mu^2+\mu^2+e^2=2016$ which implies that $a^2+2\mu^2+e^2=2016$. But from here I am stuck, I can't seem to get the sides of the two biggest squares in terms of $\mu$. I tried making triangles by considering the diagonals going through the two and second two smallest squares but with no successes. I checked the answer sheet and it said that the value of $\mu^2=288$ from that it follows that $a^2+e^2=5\mu$ but even knowing what I need to get I still can't do the problem. Any help would be greatly appriciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This actually reminded me of a video by Mathologer - the image of the ponds and lawn in particular. The video in question is [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p-0SOWbzUYI), and the similarities become very apparent roughly sixteen minutes in.

Sadly, I've never tried to prove these facts myself, and they're offered without proof in the video, so this answer is incomplete in that respect. Sorry.

Consider a triangle of side lengths $A,B,C$ (need not be a right triangle). Attach a square to each of the triangle's sides. Then connect the top-right vertex of one square to the top-left of the next going clockwise. This creates side lengths of $X,Y,Z$, as below, and

$$X^2 + Y^2 + Z^2 = 3(A^2 + B^2 + C^2)$$

[image]

Let our $A,B,C$ triangle be a right triangle now with hypotenuse $C$. Repeat the setup above. We get the below:

[image]

It turns out that the area of the yellow square is equal to that we added to $C$ (i.e. $Z^2 = C^2$). Moreover, the yellow square has one fifth the area of the two orange squares (i.e. $5Z^2 = X^2+Y^2$).

---

How shall we apply these to your problem? Label the edges in the same manner as I have above (hypotenuse of the smallest right triangle is $C$, the $A$ and $C$ squares eventually form edge $Y$, etc.):

[image]

We seek $Z^2$, and know $A^2+B^2+C^2+X^2+Y^2=2016$.

However, we know $X^2+Y^2 = 5Z^2$, and $Z^2=C^2$ and thus

$$A^2+B^2+6Z^2=2016 \tag 1$$

We return to our first relation for arbitrary center triangles:

$$X^2 + Y^2 + Z^2 = 3(A^2 + B^2 + C^2) = 3A^2 + 3B^2 + 3C^2$$

We apply the $Z^2 = C^2$ and $X^2+Y^2=5Z^2$ relations and simplify, solving for $A^2+B^2$:

$$Z^2 = A^2 +B^2 \tag 2$$

Combining $(1),(2)$ is trivial and gives us

$$7Z^2 = 2016 \implies Z^2 = \frac{2016} 7 = 288$$

Comment: For the proof of the lemma, apply Cosine rule repeatedly. Notice that $ 2ac \cos B = a^ 2 + c^2 -b^2$ and so $ y^2 = a^2 +c^2 + 2ac \cos B = 2a^2 + 2c^2 - b^2 $.

Comment: @CalvinLin thanks for the response. I think there is a difference of notation here, could you possibly expand on your explenation?

Comment: By $\cos B$, I meant $ \cos \angle ABC$. And $a, b, c$ represent side lengths of the triangles, instead of $A, B, C$ that was used. Apart from that, which of the 2 equations didn't make sense to you?

Comment: Hello, I think there might be a mistake. You are assuming that angle abc is the same as angle yac, which is the case for when it is 90 degrees but this doesn't hold for the other sides. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: No, I am not assuming the 2 angles are equal, and in fact they are not unless one of them is right. What is true is that the 2 angles sum up to 180 degrees (since the other 2 angles are right), hence have negative cosines of each other. Notice that for $y^2$, I took the positive cosine of B. (Sorry, no vertices are labelled, which makes it painful to talk about specific points.)

Comment: Thank you very much it has really made it way clearer.

Answer (score 1):

HINT

Use the law of cosines in each of two triangular flowerbeds.  The cosines are easily obtained from the right triangles.